# How to calculate the day difference for same events

Tags: mysql

My goal is to `GROUP (eid) SORT BY dayatime()`, pick the first 2 times in each group, cal the day difference.

I know that idea but how could I translate it into real MySQL query syntax ?

```
mysql> select * from events;
+------+------------+
| eid  | dt         |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2013-01-01 | -> 3
|    1 | 2013-01-04 | -> 1
|    1 | 2013-01-05 |
|    2 | 2013-04-01 | -> 7
|    2 | 2013-04-08 |
+------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


GOAL: query that gives this result: 
+------+------------+-----------------+
| eid  | dt         | days_until_next |
+------+------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 2013-01-01 |               3 |
|    1 | 2013-01-04 |               1 |
|    2 | 2013-04-01 |               7 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you want `lead()` functionality, but MySQL does not support this function.  Instead, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select e.eid, e.dt, datediff(next_dt, dt) as days_until_next
from (select e.*,
             (select dt
              from events e2
              where e2.eid = e.eid and e2.dt > e.dt
             ) as next_dt
      from events e
     ) e
where next_dt is not null;
```